# Selenium - How to get the text from an element but retaining child element source

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, innerhtml

Using Python 3 and Selenium 4.8.0.

Suppose I have

```
<p>
    I love <i>pizza</i>.
</p>
```

Having done

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
```

`elem.text` will contain "I love pizza."

What I want, however, is to somehow retain the information of what text is italicized such that I can automatically generate a `.tex` file containing, e.g.

```
I love \textit{pizza}.
```

In simple cases, one option would be to find the child `<i>` element and use string replace methods, but this leads to obvious problems if the child text is contained elsewhere in `elem`, e.g. `<p>I love <i>love</i> pizza.</p>`.

How might I get around this?

***Update***: Ultimately the LaTeX (like the one in the question), but all I really need help with is getting to some intermediate step such as ["I love ", "pizza", "."] where I know that it alternates between italicized or not, or even just getting the text back as something like "I love *pizza*." would be great.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Ultimately the LaTeX (like the one in the question), but all I really need help with is getting to some intermediate step such as ["I love ", "pizza", "."] where I know that it alternates between italicized or not, or even just getting the text back as something like "I love <i>pizza</i>." would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text *`I love <i>pizza</i>`* instead of the *text* attribute, you need *`innerHTML`* as follows:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```